# .AddOAuth() vs .AddOpenIdConnect()

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

People,

Can you clarify for me what difference and purpose is of these two methods:

1. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OAuthExtensions.AddOAuth();
2. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OpenIdConnectExtensions.AddOpenIdConnect().

According to name one is used to authorize, another to authenticate user, right?
So if my mvc application needs to know who user is I need to use `.AddOpenIdConnect()` to fetch `id_token`? And if I need to call resource service from mvc application on behalf of current user I need to add `.AddOAuth()` to get `access_token`?

Experiments with auth0.com showed that code with `.AddOAuth()` is able to get access token as result of `HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")`, but nothing if `HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token")`.

And visa versa - `.AddOpenIdConnect()` can get id_token, but no access_token.

Configuration for both is equal:

```
.AddOAuth("oauth", o =>
            {
                o.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://<Realm>.auth0.com/authorize?audience=resourceAPI-server";
                o.TokenEndpoint = "https://<REALM>.auth0.com/oauth/token";
                o.ClientId = "<clientID>";
                o.ClientSecret = "<secret>";
                o.CallbackPath = "/cb_oauth";
                o.SaveTokens = true;

            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("openIdConnect", o =>
            {
                o.Authority = "https://<REALM>.auth0.com";
                o.ClientId = "<clientID>";
                o.ClientSecret = "<secret>";
                o.CallbackPath = "/cb_openIdConnect";
                o.SaveTokens = true;
                o.Events =new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                {
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = rc =>
                    {
                        rc.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("audience","resourceAPI-server");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            })
```

It is really strange, as I can get both tokens (access and id) in postman with code flow and scope `openid email profile`.

Also tutorials on auth0.com show that .AddOpenIdConnect() with additional scope can get access token as well.
Very confusing.

So, which one for what case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `OAuth 2.0` Framework describes overarching patterns for granting authorization but does not define how to actually perform authentication.

`OpenID Connect` or `OIDC` is an OAuth extension which adds and strictly defines an ID Token for returning user information - is a profile of OAuth 2.0 that defines a workflow for authentication.

> So if my mvc application needs to know who user is I need to use .AddOAuth()

The recommended way is using OIDC , OpenID connect will give you an access token plus an id token. The id token is a JWT and contains information about the authenticated user. Your client app will validate token,decode token to get user's profile information with the help of `AddOpenIdConnect` extension .

But you can still use `AddOAuth` , the difference is OAuth needs you to get access token from IDP to access  identity provider's user management endpoint , which returns user's profile information .

> And if I need to call resource service from mvc application on behalf of current user I need to add AddOpenIdConnect() to get access_token?

OIDC is an OAuth extension , so you can use either one to get access token for accessing protected resource .

> It is really strange, as I can get both tokens (access and id) in postman with code flow and scope openid email profile.
>   Also tutorials on auth0.com show that .AddOpenIdConnect() with additional scope can get access token as well. Very confusing.

`openid email profile`are OIDC scopes . If using code flow , you didn't provider your scope ,only OIDC's scopes , a bearer access token is also included. This is to ensure the token response is compliant with the OAuth 2.0 spec. For basic OpenID authentication requests where only an ID token is requested this access token is nominal and may be safely ignored. The access token however comes into play when also requesting access to user profile data at the UserInfo endpoint.

But when you want to acquire access token for accessing protected resource/API , you need to register the resource on IDP(Auth0) and add OIDC Scope , so that Auth0 can ask user's consent to get access token .

Comment: Hi Nan, Appreciate your answer. Probably I was not correct in when said "my mvc application needs to know who user is I need to use .AddOAuth()".. should be .AddOpenIdConnect. Corrected.

But still not clear. You say that by using .AddOpenIdConnect() access bearer token is given as extra information? Does it mean that .AddOpenIdConnect() is "better" to use as it will give both tokens, id_token and access_token? So, what method (methods) should be used for case when user should be authenticated and authorized to call api?

Comment: `You say that by using .AddOpenIdConnect() access bearer token is given as extra information?` It gives ID token which include user info .`Does it mean that .AddOpenIdConnect() is "better" to use as it will give both tokens, id_token and access_token` if your application wants to get user's info easilier during authentication and want to refresh access token when token expires ,then yes , use OIDC . See also :https://blog.runscope.com/posts/understanding-oauth-2-and-openid-connect

Comment: ok. cool. 
This article talks in depth about Oauth/Oidc difference.
https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/

What  bothers me that with .AddOpenIdConnect()  HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token") doesn't returns token, only id_token.
Then in order to get access_token .AddOauth() should be used..
Unless I use it in wrong way.

Comment: @VitaliyMarkitanov , that usually is because you use the wrong flow , try setting  `ResponseType` to `code` of `AddOpenIdConnect` to use code flow : https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-openid-connect-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: YES. ResponseType = "code" helped. I though default value would be code.. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Good to see you folks are already having the conversation that was on my mind: Use opaque tokens where possible is where I come down on this.  If you can make the second callback through a back channel to get the user information, not only can you get more robust information, but you prevent the exposure of possibly sensitive data.  Still ... If someone gets a hold of your token, you got big problems.